# Empty space after unordered list item

Tags: html, css

There is unwanted space after unordered list shown in IE and Firefox in the last HTML `<li>` item that can't be removed with reducing the ul width. Anyone have idea how to remove the space? Thanks.

```css
#menubar {
  width:249px;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin-top:5px;
  padding:0;
  height:26px;
} 
.toggle {
  margin:0;
  line-height:16px;
  float:left;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;  
}
.selected {
  background-color:grey;  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="menubar">
    <li class="toggle selected">HTML</li>
    <li class="toggle">HTML</li>
    <li class="toggle">HTML</li>
    <li class="toggle selected" style="border-right:none;">HTML</li>  
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t specify a fixed width on the `ul`, but make it display as `inline-block` instead. (And if you need it horizontally centered, then use `text-align:center` on the parent element.)

```css
div {
  text-align:center;
}
#menubar {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin-top:5px;
  padding:0;
  height:26px;
  text-align:left; /* reset text-align for list contents, if necessary */
} 
.toggle {
  margin:0;
  line-height:16px;
  float:left;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;  
}
.selected {
  background-color:grey;  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="menubar">
      <li class="toggle selected">HTML</li>
      <li class="toggle">HTML</li>
      <li class="toggle">HTML</li>
      <li class="toggle selected" style="border-right:none;">HTML</li>  
  </ul>
  </div> 
</body>
```